# Imputing 23andMe 3v data to v4 and v5?

Tags: vcf, imputation

The 23andMe version 3 data (v3) is now quite 'old' and new data is being collected on the updated v5 Illumina SNP-Chip ([details here](https://www.mygenefood.com/blog/understanding-23andme-chip-versions-why-v3-v4-v5-and-others-can-differ/#how_do_the_various_chips_differ)).

Is there an online service for imputing 23andMe v3 files to v4 and v5?

Seems this would be quite handy!

Comment: I am seriously not sure why is this getting downvoted, I find the post-edit question a clear cut reasonable

Comment: Thanks Kamil, I was surprised... Good to know it's not just me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different V numbers are just different number of SNPs as far as I'm aware. So there's not going to be a service which just imputes the variants to make e.g. V3 into V5.

The [Michigan Imputation Server](https://imputationserver.sph.umich.edu/index.html#!) uses the Haplotype Reference Consortium to impute genotypes and allows input in 23andme format. You'll end up with many more SNPs than in the V5 chip, but filtering out the other ones should be easy.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. I'm now curious what coverage of v5 you get from v3 :-)